# How can I export and import a static in a component in React Native?

Tags: static, components

I'm really new in this ReactJS/React Native thing and found something I just don't understand. 
I'm creating static in every screen with the header, which can be different from a screen to another. So for example, my Home looks like this:

```
    static navigationOptions = {
        headerTitle: () => <HeaderLogo />,
        headerTintColor: "#fff",
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#DA1A31",
            elevation: 0,
            shadowOpacity: 0,
            height: 60
        },
        headerLeft: (
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Image
                    source={require('../assets/chevronback.png')}
                    style={{marginHorizontal: 20}}
                    size={15}
                />
           </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerRight: (
            <Image
            source={require('../assets/menu.png')}
            style={{marginHorizontal: 15}}
            size={20}
          />
        ),
    };

    render() {
        return (
///etc
```

But when I put my home element in App.js, the header is not there:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (

      <Home/>
    )
  }
```

What can I do for the header to show in my home screen? Is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on the react navigation header, i woud suggest to make your own custom header , which would be global component and you can import it in every screen which would act as a header and pass title of screen for the header .

First ive creater a `header.js` class component :

```
  export default class Header extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {

            }
        }

        render(){
            return(
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row' , paddingBottom :hp("3.125%") , justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                    <View style={{opacity:0}}>
                        <Image  source={require('../assets/images/crossIcon.png')} />
                    </View>
                    <View >
                        <Text style={headerStyles.headerText}>{this.props.title}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{left:-20}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={headerStyles.imageView} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                            <Image style={{height:15,width:15}} source={require('../assets/images/crossIcon.png')} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
```

then suppose in my Home.js ive imported the header class and passed the title an navigatiobn props to it :

```
import Header from '../components/Header';

class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
}

render(){

return(
<View>
<Header title="Home page" navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
</View>
)
}
}
```

Hope it helps feel free for doubts.